# Lyft API Android integration?

Tags: android, api, rest, curl, lyft-api

I'm trying to get the price of a Lyft for a certain path. Here is Lyft's authentication curl request, which is required to then request price:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --user "<client_id>:<client_secret>" \
     -d '{"grant_type": "client_credentials", "scope": "public"}' \
     'https://api.lyft.com/oauth/token'
```

I believe the new android does not allow HTTP clients, so I'm super confused on how to make this request. My requests keep failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**here is solution..**

**which works for me..Take a look may be it will be useful to you also..notify me if yes**

```
private void LyftCabAPI(){//to get uber cab info in given source and destination
    class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog2 = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);//
            pDialog2.setMessage("Searching Cabs.....");
            pDialog2.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog2.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog2.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected  String doInBackground(String...params) {
            try {
                /************** For getting response from HTTP URL start ***************/
                String url="https://api.lyft.com/oauth/token";
                URL object = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) object.openConnection();
                connection.setReadTimeout(60 * 1000);
                connection.setConnectTimeout(60 * 1000);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                String authorization="client id"+":"+"client secret";
                byte[] __data = authorization.getBytes("UTF-8");
                String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(__data, Base64.DEFAULT);
                String encodedAuth="Basic "+base64;
                connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", encodedAuth);

                String data =  "{\"grant_type\": \"client_credentials\", \"scope\": \"public\"}";
                OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                out.write(data);
                out.close();

                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                //String responseMsg = connection.getResponseMessage();
                //__LfytAccessResponse=responseMsg;
                Log.v("LyftAccess", "httpStatus :" + responseCode);
                if (responseCode == 200) {
                    InputStream inputStr = connection.getInputStream();
                    String encoding = connection.getContentEncoding() == null ? "UTF-8"
                            : connection.getContentEncoding();
                    __LfytAccessResponse = IOUtils.toString(inputStr, encoding);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "success";
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            Log.i(" __LfytAccessResponse", __LfytAccessResponse);
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(__LfytAccessResponse);
                accessToken = jsonObject.getString("access_token");
              Toast.makeText(getApplicaationContext(),"Access Token:"+                              accessToken,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
    sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute();
}

 **Happy Coding**
```